# Font is not being installed using WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, fonts

I'm trying to install TTF font permanently in windows using winapi, but when I place it in C:/Windows/Fonts it doesn't work.

I tried to change way of writing font into a folder, but didn't succeed.

```
if (!PathFileExistsA("C:/windows/fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf")) {
    auto hdl = CreateFileA("C:/windows/fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf", GENERIC_WRITE, NULL, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, NULL, NULL);

    DWORD written;
    WriteFile(hdl, font, 178520, &written, NULL);

    if (written < 178520) {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Could not install required fonts [error 1]", "Error", MB_OK | MB_APPLMODAL);
        CloseHandle(hdl);
        std::terminate();
    }

    CloseHandle(hdl);
    AddFontResourceA("C:/windows/fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf");
}
```

I checked MSDN and I think this is how I install fonts. However, this doesn't work somewhy.

UPD: I added error check to every single function but they're all succeed

Comment: What's the `178520` in `WriteFile(hdl, font, 178520, &written, NULL);`? This is very fishy. What is `font`?

Comment: You don't do any error checking. You ignore the return values of every single API call you make, other than `PathFileExistsA`. So, start by addressing that.

Comment: Once you've done the copying of the ttf file properly with error checking etc. Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-addfontresourcea) and especially the first paragraph of the Remarks section.

Comment: @Jabberwocky font is raw .ttf data (just read the ttf file and converted stuff to bytes), 178520 is the size.

Comment: @Rupppppppet yes, but hardcoding this value is a very bad idea, especially as you have it twice in your code.

Comment: @Rupppppppet also you should use [`SHGetSpecialFolderLocation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-ch/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetspecialfolderlocation) with `CSIDL_FONTS` instead of hardcoding `C:\Windows\Fonts`

Comment: @Jabberwocky okay, I'll use it.

Comment: Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-addfontresourcea), you need to broadcast a `WM_FONTCHANGE` message after calling `AddFontResource`, and also the installation is not permanent, it is lost when the current user session ends. To install permanently, you have to register the font in the Registry as well. Also, if `WriteFile` or `AddFontResource` fail, you should delete the file you created so `PathFileExists` won't keep detecting it on later checks.

Comment: *"but when I place it in C:/Windows/Fonts it doesn't work."* What happened if you put your raw.ttf to other place and Drectly call `AddFontResource` without copying?